# Get object by child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database looks like this:

```
{
     "users": {
          "-KL2IIz4jasq1kjdM-LA": {
               "id": "12345",
               "name": "peter",
               "email": "peter@gmail.com"
          }
          "-KL2Idasdsf34kjdM-LA": {
               "id": "45356",
               "name": "joe",
               "email": "joe@gmail.com"
          }
     }
}
```

Now I need to get joe by his id "45356". How can I archive this?

I can only get him by his $userId "-KL2Idasdsf34kjdM-LA" at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @adolfosrs's answer works, I recommend changing your data structure. If your users have a natural ID, you should be storing them under that ID.

```
{
   "users": {
      "12345": {
           "name": "peter",
           "email": "peter@gmail.com"
      }
      "45356": {
           "name": "joe",
           "email": "joe@gmail.com"
      }
   }
}
```

This allows loading them with a (fixed performance) direct lookup:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child("45356").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //data will be available on dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
        }
});
```

This is going to have a fixed performance, no matter how many users you have. A query will get slower as the number of users goes up, so hurts scalability.

Answer (score 2):

```
mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("id").equalTo("45356").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //data will be available on userSnapshot.getValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
        }
});
```